# Programmatically set android phone's background

Tags: android

I'd like to allow the user to choose a background from a list of images, the user clicks on one of them and that image is used as background for his phone. 
My app should simply be another version of the android default gallery.

Is it possible to programmatically set the phone's wallpaper?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First one, you need to set the permission in your `Manifest.xml` file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

And you can set the background with this:

```
Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);

buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}});
```

Comment: Thanks! <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" /> (with slash) to be exact.

Comment: What about if i have a url image source?

Comment: @FernandoUrban that is another question out of this topic. Specifically this question ask "I'd like to allow the user to choose a background from a list of images". I recommend you look in a separated thread.

Answer (score 13):

You can set a wallpaper using the [WallpaperManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). For example:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager =
        WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(someBitmap);
```