# How can I set the desktop pattern (background) in Android with my application (Java)?

Tags: java, android, desktop

I want my application (written in Java) to change the desktop pattern (background) in Android, after e.g. click on "change background to `cats.png`" button (in my application).

And I want that change to be made constant. When somebody change the background with my application and then turn it off or un-install it, the `cats.png` will still be the background of the system (till user will change it manually).

Also, I want to make it automatically - user press button => background of desktop being set (without any additional confirmations, fields, windows etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate permissions, then use wallpaper manager. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background) out for an example