# How to make a button set a photo to the homescreen? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, button, android-studio, wallpaper

I am creating a wallpaper app for the android platform, and I have my XML set up perfectly, but I cannot figure out a good procedure to set the selected photo to the home screen/lock screen via button. Any input is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Please check this link, it's will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background

Comment: here is a tutorial using the WallpaperManager  -- http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/set-wallpaper-using-wallpapermanager.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

add this code in your `Manifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

and then you can set the background with this code:

```
Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
            ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
            imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);

            buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }});
```

it will work.