# Change wallpaper to image selected in Listview - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to make an app with a listview that contains image preview files and when one of the images in the listview is clicked it is **set as the device's wallpaper**. My listview XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="@string/wallpaper_preview" />

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</TableLayout>
```

The Java file for the listview looks like this:

```
package biz.bigtooth.naturewallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And my main activity java file looks like this:

```
package biz.bigtooth.naturewallpapers;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "Leaves",
            "Lilacs",
            "Dandy Lions",
            "Twigs",
            "Holly",
            "White Flowers",
            "Cave Pool"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.leaves_preview,
            R.drawable.lilac_preview,
            R.drawable.dandy_lions_preview,
            R.drawable.twigs_preview,
            R.drawable.holly_preview,
            R.drawable.white_flowers_preview,
            R.drawable.cave_pool_preview

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-5164171001589422/5381023392");

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5164171001589422/5381023392");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();

            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {
            }
            String main = list.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //where i need help
        });
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("5C6759521D465119182182A234FF5CE3")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

If anyone could get me on the right track I would be very appreciative.

I DO NOT want it to apply one specific wallpaper, I want the app to recognize the image that's been clicked and apply that exact one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set android phone's background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. you should use image id in

> myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.leaves_preview)

use this code in  `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id)`

```
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.leaves_preview);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Need to set permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Comment: The only issue with your code is that it doesn't adjust for the other images. I want it to be able to figure out which image was clicked and for it to dynamically change the picture that gets set as wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the permission into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

---

You can set the background with following :

```
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER)
    private void setWallpaper(int resId) {
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(resId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_SET_WALLPAPER) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                btn.performClick();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Require permission to set Wallpaper. " +
                        "Please Allow.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

add following code into `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` as below :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER},
                            PERMISSION_SET_WALLPAPER);
                } else {
                    setWallpaper(R.drawable.splash_bg);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This still doesn't set the wallpaper to the one selected by the user. This always sets it to the same one.