# Setting the wallpaper from a gallery view?

Tags: java, android

[THIS IS MY CODE IN WHICH I WANT TO SET THE IMAGE IN selectedimgeView AS THE WALLPAPERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHFDK.png)I have created an app with gallery view in which when we click on the image in gallery view it opens in an image view above it. But now I want that selected image to set as the phone wallpaper. Can anyone help me with it. Please help anyone.

Comment: This has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to add the set wallpaper permission in your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Once thats there you can use something along the lines of this:

```
 WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Where the myWallpaperManager.setResource can also be myWallpaperManager.setBitmap etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wallpaper manager ,with wallpaper manager you can use your image with desired size.

this tutorial might probably help you 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/set-an-image-as-wallpaper-in-android/