# Place an image as wallpaper through URL

Tags: android, android-studio

My application has a gallery of Picasso that takes the image of the URL through strings, and a user when clicks on top of some image it opens on another activity and leaves the image on big screen.

In this activity I wanted to leave a button that applies the image to the wallpaper your smartphone.

**Code:**

https://github.com/tenorius/Picasso-Tutorial

Comment: you can use WallpaperManager. Here are some examples [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20054193/5308778) and [example2](https://www.android-examples.com/programmatically-set-imageview-as-android-phone-background/).

Comment: relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image

Comment: Formatting / grammar.

Answer (score 0):

To set the phone wallpaper you can use the `WallpaperManager` class.
Get it by using:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
```

and use the methods `setStream(InputStream bitmapData)` or `setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)` What ever more comfortable for you.

You can find more on it in the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream(java.io.InputStream)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)

note that you will have to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

to your manifest permissions

This should look like that:

```
Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
         wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set wallpaper in android use below code: By using WallpaperManager Class

```
Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set); ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview); imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five); buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); try { myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } } });
```

Need to set permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

I hope this helps.