# Set Wallpaper on Button Click in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am creating a wallpaper app. The app has a recycler view with an image and a button on it in each list item. The button click is used to set the wallpaper of the corresponding image to the home screen. I have successfully setup the recycler view but I have a problem in setting the wallpaper on button click.

This is my **activity_main.xml** code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This is my **MainActivity.java** file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int images[] = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5,
                    R.drawable.pic6, R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.pic9, R.drawable.pic10};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(images));

    }
}
```

This is my **ListAdapter** class which extends RecyclerView.Adapter also this class has nested class **ListViewHolder** which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

```
public class ListAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private int[] images;
    public ListAdapter(int[] images){
        this.images = images;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder listViewHolder, int i) {
        int index = images[i];
        listViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        Button setWallpaper;

        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_images);
            setWallpaper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.setWallpaper);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **list_item.xml** file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pic1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the design of each list item.

[image]

Now I want to set click on the button to set the corresponding wallpaper to the home screen. I am having trouble where to put onClick() method and how to set wallpaper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set android phone's background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background)

Comment: `onClick` to button you put inside `ListViewHolder` . Use `getAdapterPosition()` to get the clicked item position inside `ListViewHolder`.

Comment: No my question is little different I have already checked alot of solutions before asking.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: I am now facing issue with WallpaperManager I dont know which context I have to pass in WallpaperManager.getInstance() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the bindviewholder do something like this:

```
holder.setwallpaper.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {
       WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mcontext); 
       Drawable drawable = imageview.getDrawable(position);
//or if the above line of code doesn't work try fetching the image from your array list
imagelist.get(position).image
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }


            });
```

I've given you the logic try it if you face any problem contact me.

To pass context do something like this:
Inside your mainactivity class:

```
public void initializeAdapter()
    {
        absadapter localabsadapter = new absadapter(exlist,abs.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(localabsadapter);
    }
```

Inside your recyclerview:

```
Context mContext;
absadapter(List exList,Context context) {
        this.exList= exList;
        this.mContext = context;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: The problem is with WallpaperManager.getInstance(mcontext), what do you mean by mcontext?

Comment: @M Umer you need to pass your activity context while setting adapter inside the activity class pass your activity context inside the constructor

Comment: @M Umer check my updated answer i've given a demo code for that hope it help ;)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks alot!

Comment: You're Welcome ;)

Comment: Can I ask something more?

Comment: @MUmer yes sure go on

Comment: Now my wallpaper is successfully changing with the corresponding image, but the image in home screen doesn't fit to the screen. But in app the image is perfectly displaying in the fit screen.

Comment: I didn't got you can you share screenshots we can communicate via whatsapp if you want

Answer (score 0):

load image with Glide or Picasso inside `onBindViewHolder`, with Glide

```
Glide.with(this).load("image_url").into(imageView);
```

then set OnClickListener inside `onBindViewHolder` as example

```
holder.setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

inside `onClick` convert image to bitmap and set wallpaper. you can use Glide for that

```
Bitmap bitmapImage;
Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("image_url")
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        bitmapImage = resource;
                    }
                });
```

then execute SetWallpaperTask

```
new SetWallpaperTask().execute();
```

SetWallpaperTask() class like this

```
private class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapImage);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
            super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        }
    }
```