# How to "Set Current Picasso Loaded Image as wallpaper"

Tags: android

I am working on Picasso and have loaded the Images into an ImageView.What should i write on the button code to set it as android wallpaper?

I have success in setting the wallaper from drawable folder.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background

Comment: its about setting local image as wallpaper. What about Fetching from PICASSO ?

Answer (score 1):

First you get your bitmap image from **Picasso** like this :

```
Bitmap mybitmap ;

Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(new Target() {
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
     mybitmap = bitmap;
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
});
```

or you can get bitmap from Imageview like this :

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap mybitmap= imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

and then You can set a wallpaper using the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) class . For example:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(mybitmap);
```

Comment: you should write it where you want to action setting your wallpaper , it doesn't matter  imageview , you need the url the get bitmap

Comment: cannot resolve method with(context). What to do now

Comment: i think you are using another version of Picasso library , what version are you using

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Comment: i am trying now

Comment: bro , i want to see your logcat , but anyway i had a look  on your code , and i see somthing totally wrong , how could do do    ViewPager mViewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_page); before onCreate ????

Comment: the same  for btnwallpaper , you are not even instantiate it in your onCreate() ?????

Comment: sorry, my bad. Fixed it . But please say me how can i set the already loaded Picasso Image as wallpaper. Pls help

Comment: you have to get the bitmap from picasso or from the imageview check my edit

Comment: thanks, but what do i write inside the OnButtonClick in MainActivity ? just answer this pls

Comment: in yout button click you have to get the bitmap from the code i gave you and then use wallpaperManger to set bitmap as wallpaper ...all of this inside your button click listener

Comment: i give up, frustated

Comment: You can't say this c'mon ! Bro have the courage and the will to do it don't stop !

Comment: i am trying again, i tried hard but cannot understand this PagerAdapater and stuffs

Comment: Hope this help you to understand 
http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Comment: thanks so much for the Support bro, will try whole night and see if i can :)

Comment: Good luck , we all struggles at the beginning :)